# AllenNLP: How to know which index of the output-tensor corresponds to which class

Tags: allennlp

I am using allennlp 2.1 and I would like to pass class weights to the pytorch-cross-entropy loss function that I use.

```py
@Head.register('model_head_two_layers')
class ModelHeadTwoLayers(Head):

    default_predictor = 'head_predictor'

    def __init__(self, vocab: Vocabulary, input_dim: int, output_dim: int, dropout: float = 0.0,
                 class_weights: Union[List[float], None] = None):
        super().__init__(vocab=vocab)
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.layers = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Dropout(dropout),
            torch.nn.Linear(self.input_dim, self.input_dim),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            torch.nn.Linear(self.input_dim, output_dim)
        )
        self.metrics = {
            'accuracy': CategoricalAccuracy(),
            'f1_macro': FBetaMeasure(average='macro')
        }
        if class_weights:
            self.class_weights = torch.FloatTensor(class_weights)
            self.cross_ent = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=self.class_weights)
        else:
            self.cross_ent = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

In the configuration file I pass the class weights as follows:

```json
"heads": {
            "task_name": {
                "type": "model_head_two_layers",
                "input_dim": embedding_dim,
                "output_dim": 4,
                "dropout": dropout,
                "class_weights": [0.25, 0.90, 0.91, 0.94]
            }
        }
```

In order for the class weights to be in the correct order I need to know which index of the output tensor corresponds to which class. The only way to find that out, that I know of until now, is to first train a model without class weights and then go into the vocabulary directory of the model and check in which order the class names are written into the labels-file.

While that seems to work...is there an easier way to get that mapping without having to train a model first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a vocabulary without training a model by using the `allennlp build-vocab` command. But I think the better solution here would be to pass the `class_weights` to your model as a mapping from `label -> weight`, and then build the array of weights with the `__init__` function. Something like this:

```py
class ModelHeadTwoLayers(Head):
    def __init__(
        self,
        vocab: Vocabulary,
        input_dim: int,
        output_dim: int,
        dropout: float = 0.0,
        class_weights: Optional[Dict[str, float]] = None,
        label_namespace: str = "labels",
    ):
        super().__init__(vocab=vocab)

        # ...

        if class_weights:
            weights: List[float] = [0.0] * len(class_weights)
            for label, weight in class_weights.items():
                label_idx = self.vocab.get_token_index(label, namespace=label_namespace)
                weights[label_idx] = weight
            self.class_weights = torch.FloatTensor(weights)
            self.cross_ent = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=self.class_weights)
        else:
            self.cross_ent = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it seems obvious to use `vocab` :)